# AccessTokenRefreshError when building service object

Tags: heroku, oauth-2.0, google-bigquery

I have the following code that I have deployed to Heroku:

```
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
    settings.SERVICE_ACCOUNT, KEY,
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery')
self.http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
self.service = build('bigquery', 'v2', http=self.http)
self.job_runner = self.service.jobs()
```

When building the service object, I often get a AccessTokenRefreshError. In these cases, I'm aborting the request, and retrying at a later time. However, I am sometimes getting this error 10-15 times in a row. Is there something I can do to avoid this error? Can I manually refresh the token somehow? I am getting this error when running queries as well.

Comment: Do you have a full stack trace by any chance?

Comment: Here you go: https://gist.github.com/4005033

Comment: Try catching the exception and doing `dir(exception)`.  Looking for the HTTP response body for the 403 error.  Should have more info.

Comment: nope. ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getslice__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__unicode__', '__weakref__', 'args', 'message']

Comment: message() returns "Invalid response 403."

Comment: So I hacked the client to show the entire body in that message attribute in cases where the API returns invalid JSON, and received the following body while authenticating:

    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE>User Rate Limit Exceeded</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
    <H1>User Rate Limit Exceeded</H1>
    <H2>Error 403</H2>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>

Answer (score 0):

Just to start wrapping up this thread, I believe that [using Memcache](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/memcache#using-memcache-from-python) is the best way to store OAuth2 authorization credential information that is accessible to all in a instances in a Heroku Dyno.